# input npm start to start an reactjs project and it get stuck with computer can't open a website automatically

Tags: reactjs

I want create a Reactjs project,I user command as follow:

```js
npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm start
```

I have set the `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0` as the environment variable.

However, the command `npm start` get stuck ，the Command Line Tool have show **Starting the development server...** for **1 hour !** And the computer can't open a website automatically！

what should I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution is

1. reboot your computer
2. allow the IDE(e.g. VSCode) to control your computer's behaviors.

and it worked.

it associate with a permission problem

Comment: Please mark your own answer as an Answer of this question.